# The difference between the request time and the current time is too large. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: amazon-s3, upload, file-transfer, multipart

I am getting

```
The difference between the request time and the current time is too large. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

When uploading files from Windows 2012/2016 Server EC2 instances to AWS S3. I have configured NTP as well but the issue still persisted. I am connecting EC2 instances through Bomgar and uploading files through .NET utility service, which is provided by AWS only.
My local time and the current time is correct and I am using multipart upload.

Can anyone assist me please. Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: It normally means your computer has the wrong time -- check the Year as well. You could also try doing it via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to see if it works or returns the same error.

Comment: Thanks for responding John.. It is working good with AWS CLI.. even few files are uploading as well using both ways.. We are getting this issue intermittently hence unable t find out the cause